# ddd, bulk creation of aggregate and validation that requires infrastructure

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am designing an aggregate that has list of keywords as its property, and it has constraint that two aggregate cannot have same keywords as its property.

I use `repository` that has `save` and `saveAll` method when persisting aggregate, and each run in a single transaction. And `Factory` pattern is used when creating an aggregate.

When creating a single aggregate, the validation would be easy that i check if keyword is owned by others through `KeywordChecker` service that internally query the existing record for the validation.

The problem comes when i create multiple aggregates, in this case not only checking existing record with `KeywordChecker` is required, but also checking **pre-created, but not yet persisted aggregates** is required, because `KeywordChecker` will only check the records that are persisted.

I could put another validation logic that resembles `KeywordChecker` but that will lead me to duplicate service just working on a different dataset. Is there any elegant way to handle this issue?A

Comment: What should the behavior be when a) a user modifies one aggregate and creates a second in one action? For example, move a keyword to a new aggregate. b) Different users create new aggregates at the same time that contain the same keyword?

Comment: The rule is that aggregates are not allowed to own same keyword.
a) If user did not persist he first aggregate, then `KeywordChecker` will still check that the keyword is owned by the first aggregate, and user will not allow to create second one.

b) That should not be allowed. If i use unique constraint of database, it will be easy to do so, but then our domain model will miss the important business concern(that the same keyword cannot be owned by multiple aggregate) .

Comment: Have you considered alternative domain models, for example an aggregate that can enforce this business rule without depending on infrastructure?

Comment: @RikD, I tried, but since the aggregate is persisted in multi-thread environment, i found no way to enforce this without depending on infrastructure.

Comment: @ringord Can you clarify what you mean by "The problem comes when I *(single user ?)* create multiple aggregates"? If you create multiple aggregates as part of the same business transaction, you can check them exactly like you do with one, right? One could argue that the real problem is when *multiple* users claim the same keyword in concurrent transactions, which is harder to control...

Comment: @ringord Also, "pre-created, but not yet persisted" is very confusing. Are you talking about a domain concept called pre-creation? The moment when a user selected a keyword in the UI but hasn't hit Save yet? The brief moment when a new aggregate sits in memory on the server side but is not persisted yet?

Comment: @guillaume31 `pre-created, but not yet persisted` means the brief moment when a new aggregated sits in memory on the server, but not yet persisted to storage through repository. Aggregated is created from the factory, but it is not saved through repository.

Comment: The problem occurs, when user upload some document that contains multiple row of data, and the service handles the creation from those document within the single user request.

Comment: @ringord what prevents the keyword checker from verifying if *none* of the keywords present in all rows are 1/ duplicate within the document and 2/ already taken by existing aggregates? I think you're overcomplicating things with this multi-aggregate question, the only problem is indeed if concurrent transactions (typically by different users) touch the same keywords.

Comment: @ringord Which begs the question: are you in a highly concurrent context? Wouldn't it be enough to let the checker check the invariant and put a unique constraint in the DB? Go optimistic and if the DB constraint blows, just display an error message "sorry, someone else used your keyword at the same time".

Comment: Using db features like unique constraint will be the solution to this, but then `not allowing keyword to be owned by multiple aggregate` is one of domain rules, but will not exist in the domain.

Comment: @ringord that's why I wrote "let the checker check the invariant AND put a unique constraint in the DB".

Answer (score 3):

As you have stated, once the data is persisted it's not really a problem - any subsequent action can simply check if a conflicting record/aggregate exists.

Fundamentally the problem you are facing is one of distributed locks - you need to take a lock early on in the processing, before you are ready to persist the primary data/transaction, so that other operations can have visibility into the existence of the lock.

In order to achieve that you need to ensure that the lock is not part of the primary transaction - that might be a second DB connection (if you want to use the database for managing the lock) or you could use a dedicated service to manage the locks (such as Redis) I am assuming that the primary transaction will commit in some reasonably short amount of time so you can use a simply strategy such as locks expiring after 10 seconds to ensure that you don't end up with orphaned locks, if there is some bug in your code.

## Edit: Integration of Locks into the design

From a business perspective I would consider the `Keywords` to be a finite resource - i.e. there is only one of each that can be **REFERENCED** in the main aggregate. I see this as analogous to `Orders` and `Inventory` i.e. if the business requirement is that items can only be added to `Orders` if they are in stock, it becomes necessary to update both aggregates in sync (i.e. using domain events to propagate updates across aggregates).

However the point of Aggregates is that they are transaction boundaries, so in the case of the inventory example, you would probably reserve the inventory first, assign it to the order then decrement the inventory (and reservation) after the order has been shipped (i.e. the reservation remains in place until you no longer have the physical item in the warehouse).

Now applying this to `keywords` I think the root of the problem is the `keyword` is actually it's own aggregate, albeit a tiny one with almost no functionality. If you were to implement this purely as a DDD solution I think you would use a table just to store the keywords that were in use (or about to be used).

Your `KeywordChecker` service is conceptually the repository for `Keyword` aggregate - I understand it doesn't really make sense to create a table for this limited functionality (and implement all the logic to update it correctly), however I think you can still expose it as such. I.e. that the implementation of the persistence of `keywords` is based on a lock and checking the existence of those keywords in the main aggregate rather than using its own storage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, How should i adapt lock into my domain logic?
The first thing comes into my mind is creating a `KeywordLock` domain service that has `lock`, and `unlock` method receiving keyword as the parameter. And the `KeywordChecker` service will check both db and `KeywordLock` service(by checking if it can acquire a lock or not) within its `check` method. And my factory and aggregate will use the `KeywordLock` service. Nonetheless, it seems like that i brought infra concerns into my domain logic, since my domain has nothing to do with the term `lock`.

Comment: Edited answer to answer this locking question.

Comment: Thanks, instead of `KeywordChecker` service, i could use `KeywordPool` that has `pull` and `push` method, that `pull` will check the availability of keyword, acquire the lock, and `push` will just release the lock. And my factory will depend on the `KeywordPool`.  
And while writing this, a new concern comes into my mind. Although the aggregate created by factory is created, it isn't actually created in the whole system until it is persisted. So if the created aggregate is not persisted due to connection/storage error, the acquired lock must be released. continued...

Comment: To do so, not only the factory depends on the `KeywordPool` but also the domain orchestration method(I call this task handler) needs to depend on `KeywordPool` to release the lock (if i use lock without ttl feature). It feels like having another  transaction boundary surrounding our task handler. Would that be ok?

Comment: @DavidT before talking about locks, reservations and advanced concurrency management of the kind used by online stores, shouldn't we look at the domain context? What is the contention for these keywords and the impact of conflicts? If it is low and conflicts are rare, optimistic concurrency control - basically boiling everything down to "once the data is persisted" - seems like a sensible option.

Comment: @guillaume31 I think you are just moving the goal posts, at some point a request will come in with a Keyword that is already in use. The minimal implementation would be to create a new aggregate and try to save it (assuming there is a DB constraint in place) we would now need to check the error from the DB to see why the DB operation failed. I.e. we have recovery logic for a requirement that is only expressed in the DB - Moving it out of the DB requires similar complexity, but catches the problem earlier.

Comment: @DavidT You can enforce it both at the domain (aggregate or service) and DB level. The difference between optimistic and pessimistic concurrency control (locks) looks like slightly more than just moving goal posts to me. In the absence of context it is safer to recommend both options.